# accessing struct from one class to another

Tags: swift, swift-structs

Is it possible to access a struct from another class?

ex:

```
class A{
    struct structOfClassA {
        func returnLetterA () -> String{
            return "a"
        }
    }
}

class B{
    let classA = A()

    init(){
        classA.structOfClassA.returnLetterA // this is what I want to achieve
    }
}
```

how can I access the the struct from Class A() in Class B()?

is there a workaround with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure in class `A` defines a *type* (that can be used within the scope of class `A`), but you need an *instance* of it to be able to call the member functions of the structure. E.g.:

```
class A {
    struct StructOfClassA {
        func returnLetterA() -> String{
            return "a"
        }
    }

    var structOfClassA = StructOfClassA() 
        /* Instance of 'StructOfClassA' structure type */
}

class B {
    let classA = A()

    init() {
        let myLetter = classA.structOfClassA.returnLetterA()
        print(myLetter)
    }
}

var myB = B() // prints "a"
```

---

Alternatively, you can let `B` be a subclass of `A`, which gives you access to the *type* `StructOfClassA` from the superclass, in which case you could create an *instance* of `StructOfClassA` and access its method `returnLetterA()`:

```
class A {
    class StructOfClassA {
        func returnLetterA() -> String{
            return "a"
        }
    }
}

class B : A {
    let classA = A()

    override init() {
        let myLetter = StructOfClassA().returnLetterA()
        print(myLetter)
    }
}

var myB = B() // prints "a"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for very quick reply, it all make sense to me now.

Thank you!

Comment: @EncioPeter Happy to help. I'll add one additional note above.

Comment: @EncioPeter if this answered your question please make sure you accept it as the answer. This helps future users find the solution quicker!

Answer (score 0):

You have just declared the struct A in class A but you also have to create an instance from struct A.

```
class A{
    struct SomeStruct {
        func returnLetterA () -> String{
            return "a"
        }
    }
    let A = SomeStruct()
}

class B{
    let classA = A()

    init(){
        let letter = classA.A.returnLetterA() // this is what I want to achive
    }
}
```